# Debugging Grid styles and formats

Tags: html, css, debugging

I am working on an assignment where I need to debug errors in this code. I have it mainly half finished but am getting snagged on the grid styles. It is supposed to look like the picture but I cannot get it formatted correctly. Any help is appreciated. I am not looking for the answer, but a nudge in the right direction would be super helpful. Thank you [image]

```
body {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 90%;
   
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px; 
   grid-template-areas: "header header header"
                        "link link link"
                        "side1 main nav"
                        "coupon coupon coupon"
                        "sides sides sides"
                        "footer footer footer";
   grid-gap: 10px 25px;
}

/* Grid Areas */
header {grid-area: headers;}
nav.horizontal {grid-area: links;}
nav.vertical {grid-area: navs;}
article {grid-area: main;}
section {grid-area: coupons;}
aside {grid-area: sides;}
footer {grid-area: footers;}

/* Image Styles */
header img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

/* Horizontal Navigation List Styles */
nav.horizontal ul {
   width: 100%;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat (5fr, 1fr);
}
nav.horizontal ul li {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Coupon Section Styles */
section {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat (3fr, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 20px;
}

section div {
   outline: 4px dashed gray;
   position: relative;
}

section div p.last-of-type {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo `header {grid-area: headers;}` should be `header {grid-area: header;}` with no "s" to match `grid-template-areas: …`

Same for link, nav, coupon, footer

```css
header {grid-area: header;}
nav.horizontal {grid-area: link;}
nav.vertical {grid-area: nav;}
article {grid-area: main;}
section {grid-area: coupons;}
aside {grid-area: sides;}
footer {grid-area: footer;}
```

Also according to the image, it look like areas should be more something like that

```css
grid-template-areas: "header header header"
                        "link link link"
                        "side1 main nav"
                        "side1 coupon nav"
                        "footer footer footer";
```